# set ViewPager position with RecyclerView position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, conditional-statements

I'm writing software like a gallery, which I use to view the list of RecyclerView and to change the images from ViewPager.
My question: How can I use RecyclerView position in ViewPager?
I've tried several different conditions but it does not work

Thank you very much for your time gave me

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    // Get the RecyclerView position
    Intent intent = ((DetailsActivity) context).getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    int position1 = bundle.getInt("position");

    String pst = String.valueOf(position1);

    if (pst != null  ){
        position = position1;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

get position of recyclerview on its touchevent.
And use that position to set the position of viewpager.

step 1>

> find your viewpager.

step 2>

> add pagerAdapter to the viewpager.

step 3>

> set the position of viewpager with thw position that you get
>   recyclerview.

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(positionFromRecyclerview)
```